# Can infinitives be used as Subject Complements and Object Complements?

Tags: infinitives

Infinitives in sentences are qualify verbs, nouns, adjectives etc. and can be replaced with adjectives, adverbs.

Is it possible to use infinitives as object or subject complements in sentences?
Please consider these sentences. Here I've used passive past infinitives as subject complement of each verb:

> 1. He appeared **to be punished** for what he did.
> 2. He is **to be received** the money.

Also, here infinitives are used as complement of its object:

> 3. I allow him **to go**.
> 4. I found this question **to have been solved** by someone.

Again, can we use infinitives as this way in sentences? I'm little confused about infinitives and the ways its usage in sentences.

Comment: Yes, they can, but not in your examples. 1,3 and 4 are catenative constuctions where the subordinate clauses are catenative complements of the verbs "appear", "allow" and "find" respectively. 2. is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ I can't think of any situation where an infinitive is used as a predicative complement. "I considered it **to be wrong**"—is 'to be wrong' the predicative complement?

Comment: @user178049 "Consider" is a catenative verb and "to be wrong" catenative complement with "it" a raised object. Infinitivals can be PCs, for example: "His intention was for the meeting to begin at six"; "This is to prevent the cattle from wandering off"; "This is to clean the lens with". Not objective PCs though. Gerund-participials can also be PCs, both subjective and objective

Comment: @BillJ A grammar book I've referred shows that verbs like 'appear', 'allow' etc. are said to be 'Verbs of incomplete predication' as they require another word to complete the sentence. So, I thought it would be right if I use infinitive verbs with this verbs to make sense. I don't know what the 'catenative constuctions' is and how to apply this rule in sentences, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, you can use infinitival clauses with those verbs, but they are not subject or object complements. Here's a brief introduction to catenatives: [link](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=qlxDqB4ldx4C&pg=PA216&lpg=PA216&dq=catenative+construction&source=bl&ots=WRBEa3fou1&sig=AVKh_vUSlqfSqnznYTcvVMVaJKE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO6oT3sMfVAhWqAMAKHeMkDFIQ6AEIejAQ#v=onepage&q=catenative%20construction&f=false)

Comment: @BillJ Would you create an answer so that the OP and others can upvote and accept it?

Comment: '1.You **are requested** to act in their next show' '2.You **seem** to be requested in their next show' Are this both sentences grammatically right? I suppose they are _catenative constuctions._

Comment: I don't understand how these comments with highly technical terms **with no explanation of them** can be understood by ELLers. What's the point?? [He is to be received the money.=buzzer]

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine except 2, but not because it's an infinitive.

Take 1 for exampe ...

> He appeared to be punished for what he did = Someone punished him for what he did.

This is fine.

> He is to be received the money = Someone received him the money (Fails).

Since *receive* doesn't take two objects it doesn't work.  You can't use *receive* as in "getting something" passively. But no issue with the infinitive.  E.g. *He is to be given the money* works.

Answer (score 0):

> He appeared to be punished for what he did.

This is correct. You can also say ***He appeared to have been punished*** if you want to emphasize that the punishment happened in the past.

> He is to be received the money.

This is incorrect. You can say ***He is to receive the money*** or ***He is to have received the money***, but it doesn't make sense to use the passive infinitive form of ***receive*** in this sentence.

> I allow him to go.

This is fine.

> I found this question to be solved by someone.

This is incorrect. Because ***found*** is past tense, the infinitive must also be past tense. So you could say ***I found this question to have been solved by someone***. But it's more common to say ***I found this question solved by someone.***

Comment: I see a problem with my own answer, but unsure what's wrong with it. Both "found" and "appeared" are past tense, so by my own logic both sentences should be ungrammatical. For some reason "appeared to be punished" feels OK to me.

Comment: Yes, but the question was whether the infinitival clauses can be used as subject and object complements.

Comment: No, there is nothing "incorrect" in his sentences save in number 2. They are far from felicitous, but they are grammatically justifiable. In none of them, though, is an infinitival used as a subject or object complement.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thank for you comment. Can you give me some examples for usage of infinitives as subject/object complements, or any reference for study?

Comment: @YasmikaSaubhagya If you look at my message to user178049, you'll see three examples of infinitvals as subject complement.